# How to send mutiple text messages from an android app?

Tags: android

Sorry if this question is already asked or seems stupid but i am stuck . I am writing an android application in which app sends different messages to different people the first one successfully send but there is a problem with the second one it doesn't show me error but it doesn't send the second message here is a portion of my code

```
public void sendSMSMessenger(){
    Log.i("Send SMS", "");



    try {
            // SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
             SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(Emergencyphonenumber, null, "There is an emergency with your "+PatientRelationship+" "+Patientname+" please open the link to find the location   "+"https://www.google.com/maps/place/"+latitude+","+longitude, null, null);
             Toast.makeText(this, "Message Sent (Relative)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(Doctorphonenumber, null, "There is an emergency with your patient named "+Patientname+" please open the link to find the location   "+"https://www.google.com/maps/place/"+latitude+","+longitude, null, null);
             Toast.makeText(this, "Message Sent (Doctor)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();





          } catch (Exception e) {
              Toast.makeText(this, "Message Sending failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             e.printStackTrace();
          }

}
```

Thank you....

Comment: That is because the network gets jammed when you attempt to send a message one after the other . So the solution is, try to send the next message after waiting 15-30 seconds. Hope you understood.

Comment: @Lal, Can you please clarify what you meant with "__network gets jammed__" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not send messages simultaneously. In a way its hard for network to process all the messages collectively. Wait a little. Increase the time.